# Saboteur inbetween the goal cards

Tags: saboteur

If I reach a goal card that is a rock, can I put a path card going from that goal card to another one, even though that goal card dosen't have a path connected to it on that side?

Answer (score 4):

No.

The general rule is that you orient the goal card to connect with the path you added.  That goal card is now part of your path, and to add a path from there, it has to correctly match the path on the goal card.